# In Google Test, how to do tear down in the face of assertion failures?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I'm trying to figure out how to do TearDown() in the face of ASSERT failures in Google Test.

A dummy example is below:

```
class TestFixture: public testing::Test 
{
protected:
  virtual void SetUp() 
  {
      // Do per test setup
  }

  virtual void TearDown() 
  {
      // Do per test teardown
  }

}

TEST_F(TestFixture, MyTest)
{
  ASSERT_TRUE(false);
}
```

What I'm trying to acheive is for TearDown() to be called even if the test throws an assertion failure. GoogleTest doesn't call TearDown() when an assertion is thrown. How do I go about this?

Comment: Are you sure the library behaves that way? As of right now [(r609) `Test::Run`](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/src/gtest.cc#2153) always calls `TearDown`, even if there were fatal failures in `TestBody`.

Comment: You are right! I think if the test is singly threaded TearDown is called irrespective of fatal failures. I assumed otherwise because, because my test is multi-threaded. And TearDown() is not being called in this case when the test body throws an assertion :(

Answer (score 2):

Put your setup code in the fixture's constructor, and put your tear-down code in the destructor.